# How to separate or segregate or group same pdf format in a folder?

Tags: python, pdf, automation

I have a folder full of pdf files with different format. Is it possible to separate the same format pdf into a separate folder or group them as same format pdf's.

Comment: How do you want to detect to which format does given pdf file belong?

Comment: It's almost certainly easy to do if you know how to determine the format of a pdf, but you haven't said how you define "format". Also, do you want this as a python script (based on your question tag) or something else?

Comment: @joanis The format in here I referred is the structure of PDF. Say example I have 10 PDF's in a folder in which 4 PDF has the same page numbers with same data Structure other 3 PDF has the same page & structure. So I need to group/separate each group data structure and put it in a separate folder like Group 1,2,3 respectively.

Comment: So, my question is: do you know how to determine the format programmatically, and you're asking how to separate the files given the formats you can determine? or are you asking for help determining what the format of a file is programmatically?